# Can I specify a non strict method requirement for child classes?

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

I have a base class in which I want to specify the methods a child class must have, but not implement them itself. However, the methods in a child class may have a different number of paramaters to the definition in the base class.

Having tried this with an abstract method, php doesn't allow this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of specifying the abstract method with no parameters and requiring the subclassed method to access the args through func_get_args, I don't see how this would be possible.

Comment: The flip-side of this is to only take a single argument and require all arguments to be passed in through arrays.

Answer (score 6):

The child class's function can add extra, optional arguments to the signature without it causing errors:

```
abstract class Foo {
  abstract function bar($a);
}

class NewFoo extends Foo {

  function bar($a, $b = null) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is one of the weak points of PHP's object orientation, that it wasn't designed to handle this kind of use case.  It just wasn't meant to allow overloaded methods for its

It is indeed possible to do what you're talking about as a kind of hack, in both the way mentioned above with:

```
func_get_args()
```

or, just (like the commenter mentioned) pass in an array of arguments. Alternately you could pass in an object that has your arguments as data members.  Then you could extend the parameter/argument object for your child method.

The point is that PHP is a language that **thrives on permissiveness and not restriction**.  Abstract classes have a very basic implementation in PHP.  If you have the need for a lot of structure like this, then PHP really might not be the best language choice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an answer that you will want to use in production as it will be fairly slow, but just for the sake of it I tried to write something using Reflection, which seems to work. You will still get an E_STRICT because method declarations in subclasses are apparently supposed to match.

```
class a {
    protected $requiredMethodsInSubclass = array( 'method1', 'method2', 'method3' );

    public function __construct() {
        $reflObject = new ReflectionObject($this);

        $className = $reflObject->getName();

        if ($className == __CLASS__) {
            //this class is being instanciated directly , so don't worry about any subclasses
            return;
        }

        foreach ($this->requiredMethodsInSubclass as $methodName) {
            try {
                $reflMethod = $reflObject->getMethod($methodName);
            } catch (ReflectionException $e) { //method not anywhere
                trigger_error("Method $methodName is not declared in class " . __CLASS__ . " or subclass $className", E_USER_ERROR);
                continue;
            }

            $declaringClass =  $reflMethod->getDeclaringClass();

            if ($declaringClass->getName() == __CLASS__) {
                //method is declared in this class, not subclass
               trigger_error("Method $methodName is not declared in subclass $className", E_USER_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }

    public function method1() {

    }

    public function method2($a) {

    }
 }



class b extends a {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //some stuff
    }


    public function method2($a, $b, $c) {

    }

}



$b = new b();
```